# RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient unable to CreateAssessment in .NET Framework Application

Tags: .net, recaptcha-enterprise

I have a .NET Framework 4.8 Application (for testing purposes, I have made this a console app). I am trying to use Google ReCaptcha Enterprise through the Google Client Libraries (Google.Cloud.RecaptchaEnterprise.V1) nuget package. I have it set up almost identical to how Google has provided it in the sample (https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-assessment). I have authentication set up correctly (verified because I am able to get beyond the client initialization), but when I go to create the assessment, I get the following error:

> Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="failed to connect to all
> addresses",
> DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException:
> {"created":"@1657548977.660000000","description":"Failed to pick
> subchannel","file":"......\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":3218,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1657548977.660000000","description":"failed
> to connect to all
> addresses","file":"......\src\core\lib\transport\error_utils.cc","file_line":165,"grpc_status":14}]}")

Has anyone run into this issue? This is the code I am using:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient client = RecaptchaEnterpriseServiceClient.Create();

    var projectName = new ProjectName("[insert project name]");

    CreateAssessmentRequest createAssessmentRequest = new CreateAssessmentRequest()
    {
        Assessment = new Assessment()
        {
            Event = new Event()
            {
                SiteKey = "[insert site key]",
                Token = "[insert token]",
                ExpectedAction = "login",
            }
        },

        ParentAsProjectName = projectName
    };

    Assessment assessmentResponse = client.CreateAssessment(createAssessmentRequest);

    Console.WriteLine(assessmentResponse.Name);
}
```

Comment: When we've seen issues like this ("failed to connect to all addresses") it's pretty much *always* been due to a network issue, the common ones being: 1) a locked-down network that only permits connections to allow-listed addresses; 2) a proxy that doesn't support HTTP/2.0 (or doesn't support it properly); 3) a proxy that *does* support HTTP/2.0 but needs to be configured to do so. I'd encourage you to talk to your network folks to see if they can help troubleshoot.

Comment: I've just double-checked that I can access the API with the library, and it is indeed fine - I can successfully list the keys, and when I try to execute a request like the one in your question (with a knowingly-bad site key and token as I don't have them) I get a meaningful error that shows it's managed to access the server correctly.